# Как сделать одинаковые текст на кнопках, но чтоб при нажатиях были разные команды? Telebot Python

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать одинаковые текст на кнопках, но чтоб при нажатиях были разные команды?
Я знаю мне нужно callback_data. Нашел решение, но только в InlineButton, а мне нужны обычные
Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, каждой кнопке назначить свой смайлик, и в коде через == сравнивать смайлик+текст, иначе - только через инлайн-кнопки, callback_data существует только в них.